# Efficient way to remove a list of strings from a 2D array (list of lists) in Python?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have quite a large dataset in the form of a list of lists. Basically, these list of lists are tokenized sentences (Each row is a sentence and each sentence is tokenized).

`train_dataset` - The 2D array (or list of lists) contain around 150000 sentences/rows and each sentence roughly contains 12 to 15 words.

`td` - Another 1D list contains 55000 UNIQUE words. If any word from these words are present in the 2D array, I need to replace them with .

I tried below ways to do so but they take a very long time, even in Google Colab's different runtime environments:

```
train_dataset = ['<UNK>' if train_dataset[i][j] in td else train_dataset[i][j] for i in range(0,len(train_dataset)) for j in range(0,len(train_dataset[i])) ]
train_dataset
```

I also tried to convert the list to NUMPY arrays and try so. Still no luck.

```
import numpy as np
np_tr = np.array(train_dataset)
for st in td:
  for i in range(0,len(np_tr)):
    for j in range(0,len(np_tr[i])):
      if np_tr[i][j] == st:
        np_tr[i][j] = '<UNK>'
```

I want to know if there is any efficient way to do this in Python. I don't have access to PySpark or Hadoop to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the 1D list to a `set`. That should make lookup `O(1)` as opposed to `O(len(td))`. Then you should be able to do what you were doing before and it should be quite a bit faster I think. Keep in mind that what you were doing was actually flattening the 2D list into a 1D list. I'm not sure if that is what you want.

```
td = set(td)
train_dataset = ['<UNK>' if train_dataset[i][j] in td else train_dataset[i][j] for i in range(0,len(train_dataset)) for j in range(0,len(train_dataset[i]))]
train_dataset
```

Comment: The 1D list has a unique list of words i.e. length of list  = length of set.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the difference between lists and sets then. Checking if something is in a set is a constant time operation. Checking if something is in a list is a linear operation as you have to scan the list. That makes a huge difference.